# How to convert pdf file into png (image) file in QT

Tags: qt, pdf, png

I have following code

```
QString filePath("x.pdf");
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setCreator(PRODUCT_NAME);
printer.setOutputFileName(filePath;
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
QPainter painter(&printer);
render(&painter);
```

how can I save this above PDF file x.pdf into a png file  using QT code?

Answer (score 1):

Qt has no built-in methods that allow to convert PDF files to images. You should use some other libraries or call from your program some external converter. Maybe try with [Poppler](https://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt5/):

```
QImage image = pdfPage->renderToImage(xres, yres, x, y, width, height);
image.save("convertedDocument.png");
```

Comment: as I understand it is available only after qt5  but I an using version of qt.4.3.3

Comment: No, there is also version for Qt4. Please look here: https://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt4/ and https://poppler.freedesktop.org/releases.html