# Can we save png file using QPrinter?

Tags: qt, pdf, png

Using the same example as this in

[How to convert pdf file into png (image) file in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736885/how-to-convert-pdf-file-into-png-image-file-in-qt/45737604?noredirect=1#comment78461139_45737604)

Is there any way we can use QPainter to save png file. Please see the example below

```
QString filePath("x.pdf");
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setCreator(PRODUCT_NAME);
printer.setOutputFileName(filePath;
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);
QPainter painter(&printer);
render(&painter);
```

I tried the above code but it is not working in my case.The image is not proper.

Comment: What do you mean the image is not appropriate ?. One thing is that it does not generate an image and the other is that it generates it in a wrong way, what is your case?

Comment: It generates the image in wrong way

Comment: You can show the image you get and the one you should get.